# jQuery - When page is not at the top then change div background color

Tags: jquery

Ok so I have a div that is a white background when the page loads, however I wish it to change color when the page is scrolled but return to white if the page is returned to the top.

I'm just getting started with jQuery so really appreciate your help here :)

Comment: [`if($(document).scrollTop() == 0) { $('#yourdiv').css('background', 'white'); } else { $('#yourdiv').css('background', 'red'); }`](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/#scrollTop1) - [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fu2mgpcp/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to start by listening for the `window`'s "[scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)" event.  Then, you want to check the `window`'s "[scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/)" to determine if it's at the top.  Finally, you can change the page's background color using the [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) command.

Here's a (completely un-tested) example that should give you an idea:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
        $(document.body).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
    } else {
        $(document.body).css('backgroundColor', 'white');
    }
});
```